# Is "Dragon Ball AF" a real continuation of Dragon Ball series?

Tags: dragon-ball-series

I have read a manga called *Dragon Ball AF* by Toyble and I wonder if it is a continuation of the *Dragon Ball* series?

Comment: DB: AF isn't real. It's a fan creation. Read more about it here: http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Ball_AF

Comment: but toyble worked aside akira toriyama

Comment: `Within the realm of officially-licensed properties (which are produced by or with the approval of Bird Studio, Shueisha, and Toei Animation), Dragon Ball AF simply does not exist. Any AF dōjinshi, should they even exist, occupy the same canonical status as fan fiction and fan art.` Neither Toriyama or Toei or other franchise holders have officially supported or announced it.

Comment: your 23 days too late to spark this.

Comment: @Memor-X what do you mean?

Comment: @XBOveRLorD one of the many definitions of AF (After Fall, Alt Future, Another Fanfic, etc) is April Fools and before Super's release i tend to start hearing word on AF again when April Fools Day rolled in

Comment: @Memor-X wouldn't that have made him too early, since it wasn't April yet?

Comment: @MichaelMcQuade ahhh your right. I must have misremembered the order of months for Autumn since I am always wanting them to be over as quickly as possible because of the increased fire danger in Australia

Answer (score 4):

No, it isn't included in actual series. It is as you can say a fan-made because *DBZ* was off for so many years and fans were excited for any new glitch that this universe makes. The latest series is *Dragon Ball Super*.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's fan made, it's not supported by any of the official owners of the Dragon Ball franchise, and it's been denied by 2 owners as well. Along with the lack of merchandise, and lack of advertising, I think that is enough evidence to say it is fake.

proof/support for claim: http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Ball_AF
more proof/support :
http://thedaoofdragonball.com/blog/fans/dragon-ball-af-explained/

Comment: it's best to quote the relevant points from the links you use should the links ever die. also it's best to  [edit your previous answer](http://anime.stackexchange.com/posts/32355/edit) to improve it rather than post a new one